# Algorithms for constrained clustering on attributed graphs with some cluster-level constraints on their attributes

Tags: python, constraints, cluster-analysis, graph-theory

I have a graph with 240k nodes and 550k edges with five attributes per node coming out of an autoencoder from a sparse dataset. I'm looking to partition the graph into n clusters, such that intra-partition attribute similarity is maximized, the partitions are connected, and the sum of one of the attributes doesn't exceed a threshold for any given cluster.

I've tried poking around with an autoencoder but had issues making a loss function that would get the results I needed. I've also looked at heirarchical clustering with connectivity constraints but can't find a way to enforce my sum constraint optimally. Same issue with community detection algorithms on graphs like Louvain.

If anyone knows of any approaches to solving this I'd love to hear it, ideally something implemented in Python already but I can probably implement whatever algorithm I need should it not be. Thanks!

Comment: With hierarchical clustering, once you have managed to enforce the connectivity constraint, can't the attribute similarity be represented by distances between nodes ?
In any case, interesting question, I think you're in for a home-made implementation on this one.

Comment: I was able to do that with hierarchical clustering but the sum constraint kept coming up as an issue. I can force it to stop merging a cluster after it meets a threshold but I'm fairly certain the solution will no longer be optimal once I start imposing that condition.

Comment: About optimality -> your problem sounds a lot like a NP-(very)hard one, so I'm not sure that there can be any hope of reaching a real optimum here. But I agree that enforcing this condition would probably really decrease the quality of the solution. Did you try to post your question on the [computer science stack exchange](stackexchange.com) ? Could be a good move.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the problem is most likely NP-hard, so the best you can do is some greedy optimization. It will definitely help to first break the graph into subsets that cannot be connected ever (remove links of nodes that are not similar enough, then compute the connected components). Then for each component (which hopefully are much smaller than 250k, otherwise tough luck!) run a classic **optimizer** that allows you to specify the cost function. It is probably a good idea to use an integer linear program, and consider the Lagrange dual version of the problem.